# Snackbar duration is not working properly when returning to previous activity

Tags: android, android-snackbar

I have a snackbar instance in `BaseActivity` which is shown when a network error occurred. Also a handler updating this. On my `MainActivity` Snackbar is showing with **LENGTH_INDEFINITE**.

When I'm moving to some other activity with `extends BaseActivity`, then Snackbar is not staying **LENGTH_INDEFINITE** instead its duration behaving like **LENGTH_LONG**.

Again I return to the `MainActivity` then snackbar is behaving like **LENGTH_SHORT**. 
But I'm creating the snakbar with same duration. Even I'm instantiating the Snackbar with new Snackbar.

I've used `BaseActivity` container as Snackbar view parameter.

here is the code for creating snackbar which is in the `Utils` class

```
public Snackbar showSnackbar(String msg , View parent, 
                          View.OnClickListener clickListener){
    Snackbar snackbar =Snackbar.make(parent, msg, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
            .setAction("CLOSE", clickListener)
            .setActionTextColor(
                    context.getResources()
                           .getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_light ));
    snackbar.show();
    return snackbar;
}
```

Here is the `BaseActivity` method for showing Snackbar

```
private void showSnackBar(){
            if(mSnackbar  != null){
                mSnackbar.dismiss();
            }
            mSnackbar  = Utils.getInstance(mContext).
                         showSnackbar(getString(R.string.network_error_message), 
                         activityContainer , null);
        }
```